# SwiftUI: How to let a view extend past safe area and center between screen to and bottom?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, layout

I have code that's similar to:

```
var body: some View
{
    VStack
    {
        Image("someImage")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)

        Image("someImage")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)

        Image("someImage")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    }
}
```

My image has a 1:1 aspect ratio. On iPhone this would mean that there's not enough vertical space to fit them.

Currently the images are vertically compressed.

How can I make sure that all three images fill the width of the screen, that the middle image is centered, and that the top and bottom images extend past the top and bottom edges of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

The `resizable` modifier will tell the image to fill the space of its parent without caring about the original aspect ratio.
What you want is to force the image to maintain its aspect ratio, while occupying all available space (`contentMode: .fill`):

```swift
Image(systemName: "someImage")
  .resizable()
  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
  .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
```

If you place more items in a `VStack` than is visible on screen, the contents will already extend past the bounds of the screen (and the safe area), unless that content explicitly sizes to fit its parent.
You can see this behaviour by changing `contentMode` to `.fit`.

| Fit | Fill |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something simple. Now, do you know how to make sure that my middle (I have 3 images) is vertically centered between screen top and bottom, ignoring safe area? (Your images aren't precisely centered either: your first image is visible a bit more than your third.)